# Create a variable table

Tags: tabularx

I'm trying to create a variable table depending on the sentences I want to be in it. Sometimes I will need all of them, sometimes not. This is what I've got for now.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\newenvironment{competences}{
    \tabularx{\linewidth}{|m{1cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}
    \hline
}{
    \endtabularx
}

\newcommand{\communiquer}[1]{
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\cellcolor{violet!25} \textbf{Communiquer}}\\\hline
    \IfSubStr{#1}{1}{ & Faire le lien entre le langage naturel et le langage algébrique. Distinguer des spécificités du langage mathématique par rapport à la langue française.\\\hline}{}
    \IfSubStr{#1}{2}{& Expliquer à l'oral ou à l'écrit (sa démarche, son raisonnement, un calcul, un protocole de construction géométrique, un algorithme), comprendre les explications d'un autre et argumenter dans l'échange.\\\hline}{}
    \IfSubStr{#1}{3}{& Vérifier la validité d'une information et distinguer ce qui est objectif et ce qui est subjectif ; lire, interpréter, commenter, produire des tableaux, des graphiques, des diagrammes. \\\hline}{}  
}

\begin{document}

\begin{competences}
    \communiquer{2}
\end{competences}

\end{document}
```

This works juste fine when I use the command `\communiquer{1,2,3}`, but when I use `\communiquer{2}`for example, there are two extra vertical rules at the bottom of my table. I can't figure out why !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have other macros to define besides `\communiquer`, so it's better to define an interface for them.

Here the `\maketablemacro` defines the new macro given as first argument so it prints the stated title (second argument) and chooses among the numbered paragraphs. Actually, you can choose arbitrary strings for labeling the paragraphs instead of `1`, `2` and so on.

Note that since you write in French, the texts are better set after `\begin{document}`, so you don't need to adjust punctuation.

I also got rid of `tabularx` that's not needed as the first column has known width. Don't load both `xcolor` and `colortbl`, but rather pass the `table` option to the former.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{competences}{}
 {
  \noindent
  \begin{tabular}
   {
    |m{1cm}|
    >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}
    m{ \dim_eval:n { \textwidth-4\tabcolsep-3\arrayrulewidth-1cm } }
    |
   }
  \hline
 }
 {
  \end{tabular}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\maketablemacro}{mmm}
 {% #1 is the macro to define
  % #2 is the title
  % #3 is the contents, in the form {1}{text1}{2}{text2}...
  \yohann_table_make_macro:Nnn #1 { #2 } { #3 }
 }

\tl_new:N \l__yohann_table_body_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \yohann_table_make_macro:Nnn
 {
  \cs_new:Npn #1 ##1
   {
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\cellcolor{violet!25}\textbf{#2}} \\ \hline
    \tl_clear:N \l__yohann_table_body_tl
    \clist_map_inline:nn { ##1 }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nn \l__yohann_table_body_tl
       {
        & \str_case:nnT { ####1 } { #3 } \tabularnewline \hline
       }
     }
    \tl_use:N \l__yohann_table_body_tl
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\maketablemacro{\communiquer}{Communiquer}{
 {1}{Faire le lien entre le langage naturel et le langage algébrique.
     Distinguer des spécificités du langage mathématique par rapport
     à la langue française.}
 {2}{Expliquer à l'oral ou à l'écrit (sa démarche, son raisonnement,
     un calcul, un protocole de construction géométrique, un algorithme),
     comprendre les explications d'un autre et argumenter dans l'échange.}
 {3}{Vérifier la validité d'une information et distinguer ce qui est
     objectif et ce qui est subjectif ; lire, interpréter, commenter,
     produire des tableaux, des graphiques, des diagrammes.}
}


\begin{competences}
\communiquer{2}
\end{competences}

\bigskip

\begin{competences}
\communiquer{2,1,3}
\end{competences}

\end{document}
```

I'd avoid setting `\arraystretch` to `2.5`.

[image]

The macro could as well be defined as

```
\maketablemacro{\communiquer}{Communiquer}{
 {Faire}{Faire le lien entre le langage naturel et le langage algébrique.
  Distinguer des spécificités du langage mathématique par rapport
  à la langue française.}
 {Expliquer}{Expliquer à l'oral ou à l'écrit (sa démarche, son raisonnement,
     un calcul, un protocole de construction géométrique, un algorithme),
     comprendre les explications d'un autre et argumenter dans l'échange.}
 {Vérifier}{Vérifier la validité d'une information et distinguer ce qui est
     objectif et ce qui est subjectif ; lire, interpréter, commenter,
     produire des tableaux, des graphiques, des diagrammes.}
}
```

and calling the macro like

```
\communiquer{Expliquer,Faire,Vérifier}
```

would lead to the same result.

Comment: You're right ; I have other macros to define besides communiquer. I don't know anything about Latex3 and I'm going to investigate on that front but your answer is exactly what I'm looking for !  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Rather than using `\IfSubStr` I suggest using property lists from [LaTeX3](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/expl). In addition to fixing the problem with your code this gives a nicer syntax because it allows you to use more meaningful abbreviations such as `Faire`, `Expl` etc instead of less meaningful numbers `1`, `2`, ....

Secondly, unless you also want to use these outside of a table there is no need to have a separate `\communiquer` command and a `competences` environment: you can just combine them into a single command. With this in place the code below creates its tables using the commands:

```
   \Competences{Faire}
   \Competences{Expl}
   \Competences{Faire,Ver,Expl}
```

The code below defines two (user) commands:

- `\AddCompetence` for adding or defining competences. This is used as `\AddCompetence{key}{description}`
- `\Competences` for writing a competence table. This accepts a comma separated list of keys.

The output of the MWE is:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g__sentences_prop
\tl_new:N \l_sentence_tl
% add competence: \AddCompetence{key}{description}
\newcommand\AddCompetence[2]{
    \prop_gput:Nnn \g__sentences_prop {#1} {#2}
}
% internal command that writes one line of a competence table
\cs_new_protected:Npn \l__use_sentence:n #1 {
    &
    \prop_get:NnN \g__sentences_prop {#1} \l_sentence_tl
    \tl_use:N \l_sentence_tl
    \\\hline
}
% list competences: \Competences{comma separated list of keys}
\newcommand\Competences[1]{
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|m{1cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X|}
      \hline
      \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\cellcolor{violet!25} \textbf{Communiquer}}\\\hline
      % loop through the list of keys keys and apply \l__use_sentence:n
      \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#1}
      \clist_map_function:NN \l_tmpa_clist \l__use_sentence:n
    \end{tabularx}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\AddCompetence{Faire}{Faire le lien entre le langage naturel et le langage algébrique. Distinguer des spécificités du langage mathématique par rapport à la langue française.}
\AddCompetence{Expl}{Expliquer à l'oral ou à l'écrit (sa démarche, son raisonnement, un calcul, un protocole de construction géométrique, un algorithme), comprendre les explications d'un autre et argumenter dans l'échange.}
\AddCompetence{Ver}{Vérifier la validité d'une information et distinguer ce qui est objectif et ce qui est subjectif ; lire, interpréter, commenter, produire des tableaux, des graphiques, des diagrammes}

\begin{document}

  \Competences{Faire}

  \Competences{Expl}

  \Competences{Faire,Ver,Expl}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite capable to explain what's going on in great detaill but I found this:

```
\begin{competences}
    \communiquer{1}
\end{competences}
```

Gives this output: [image: Image of output]
Just like:

```
\begin{competences}
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\cellcolor{violet!25} \textbf{Communiquer}}\\\hline 
      & Faire le lien entre le langage naturel et le langage algébrique. Distinguer des spécificités du langage mathématique par rapport à la langue française.\\\hline
      {} % This starts a new line
\end{competences}
```

Apparently the `\IfSubStr`s (for 2 and 3) are not ignored and start a new line after `\hline`.
(Note that any `\communiquer` with a 3 in its argument will give a desired result.)

An easy fix is to shuffle the position of the `\hline`s like so:

```
\newcommand{\communiquer}[1]{
    \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{\cellcolor{violet!25} \textbf{Communiquer}}   
    \IfSubStr{#1}{1}
        {\\\hline& Faire le lien entre le langage naturel et le langage algébrique. Distinguer des spécificités du langage mathématique par rapport à la langue française.}
        {}    
    \IfSubStr{#1}{2}
        {\\\hline & Expliquer à l'oral ou à l'écrit (sa démarche, son raisonnement, un calcul, un protocole de construction géométrique, un algorithme), comprendre les explications d'un autre et argumenter dans l'échange.}
        {}    
    \IfSubStr{#1}{3}
        {\\\hline & Vérifier la validité d'une information et distinguer ce qui est objectif et ce qui est subjectif ; lire, interpréter, commenter, produire des tableaux, des graphiques, des diagrammes.}  
        {}
    \\\hline
}
```

So let every next true `\IfSubStr` set the `\\\hline` for the previous one and always finish with a `\\\hline`.

This fixes your problem.

Comment: That makes sense, since I forgot to move the first `\\\hline` (the one after the multicolumn). I edited my post to fix this.